# setTimeout an ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

Is there a way to use setTimeout in this ajax call. This is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : dir+"all/money/myFile.php",
    data    : "page="+data.replace(/\&/g, '^'),
    success : function(msg) {
    var info = jQuery('.product_overview #allinfo').html();
    var url = '<a href="http://www.mySite.com/openMe/letmeview.php?preview='+msg+'.html" target="_blank" class="check_link_preview" rel="'+msg+'.html">Check Preview</a>';          jQuery('.option_additional').next().find('textarea:first').text(info+url);
                },
    complete: function() {
    jQuery('.add-to-cart button.btn-cart').delay(500).trigger('click');
}
});
```

I want to do something before this ajax will be triggered that is why I'll use setTimeout or something that would delay this action.

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So if you want to use it - why didn't you just do that?! ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: How would I put it in a setTimeout function?

Comment: Can you show me an example please using my code above. Thanks :)

Comment: uhm, have you ever used setTimeout?

Comment: any reason for that? "Won't work" is not an explanation of an issue.

Comment: @zerkms let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2212/discussion-between-elson-solano-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeSend`, 
**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YMWTU/2/)**

```
$(function() {

    function callBeforeAjax() {
        alert('and now do ajax');
    }

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: callBeforeAjax,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/",
        data: "",
        success: function(msg) {},
        complete: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Refer [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AjaxFeedback)

Comment: Uhm, cannot find `delay` property. Where have you taken it from?

Comment: Also it should be `beforeSend: callBeforeAjax`, not `beforeSend: callBeforeAjax()`

Comment: You don't need the delay property, coz the beforeSend will be called before the Ajax. I have updated my answer without the delay method, but I will add the reference now.

Comment: lol, you had to put the reference to that plugin at first then. PS: I'm not the OP ;-)

Comment: :) yeah, probably had to hey! LoL

Comment: I only realised after I posted, that's why I removed the delay method. beforeSend should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used jquery with setTimeout before but try

```
var t = window.setTimeout(function, delay);
```

replace function in the above code with your jquery function.

Answer (score 2):

In a complete function:

```
complete: function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     // your action here
  }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tols is right, it works. Try something like this: `setTimeout(function(){jQuery('.add-to-cart button.btn-cart').trigger('click');}, 500);`